# Latency of IoT Hub events by using Event Grid

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I was trying to trigger an Azure function when a device changes its connection state, so I subscribed the IoT Hub events (Device connected and disconnected) by using Event Grid to trigger my function.
Everything went okay, but I found out that the latency (time between event time and function triggered time) was around 40 seconds to a minute, which wasn't expected.

Is this normal or did I do something wrong? If it's normal, is there any workarounds or other ways to meet my needs? And it will also be great to know why this long latency happens!

Thanks for help!

Comment: When a Function hasn't received an event for a while, the startup time can increase. Is this the case in your scenario, or is it constant? If this is the case, you could try if there is any difference with a Function using the Premium plan to avoid cold starts.

Comment: @MatthijsvanderVeer Sorry for the late response. I don't think that is my case, since I tested couple of times. And I did try with the Premium plan but the results were the same. But I found out that my function was triggered around every minute when I tested it frequently(keep connecting and disconnecting my device ), which I guess the event message was actually send to Event Grid at regular intervals. 
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

Does your IotHub and Azure Function are hosted in same region.Assuming that there is no other endpoint (like EventHub) in between.

Comment: Yes, I'm only using IoT Hub and Azure function, and they are both hosted in the same region (East Asia).